# Ripping JQuery from unnecessary/unused pieces: is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, minify

Is it possible to ONLY use portions of JQuery, just like with JQuery UI: customize ones own build in an easy way?

What i mean is imagine you ONLY need JQuery library for a silly, tiny but handy tool on youw site, lets say the Dialog boxes.

Are there JQuery builts available specifically supporting portions of functionality, at a fraction of the current Javascript code sizes?

Comment: You mean a fraction of the 29k library...  What are you targeting, a C64?  :)

Comment: @gahooa: jQuery's been well over 29k for a long time, even on the minified version, unless I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @Jordan: the key is to ensure your webserver has gzip transport support, then it is only 29K.

Comment: Gotcha, I thought you were just talking about the file itself. Good times.

Comment: If someone would give me a whole big salmon fish weighing 29 units, doesn't mean I have to eat it all in one visit! I want to eat what I need. say 7 units. Is that possible with JQuery?

Comment: The question is moot as you shouldn't be serving jQuery yourself. Use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js`. Your users will likely have this cached, and nothing will be downloaded at all.

Comment: @Sam: no it isn't possible to only use a portion of jQuery. Most libraries are not that modular, particularly since you're talking about the core of jQuery. One of the 3 answers below is likely the way you should proceed. 29k is not big, and jQuery is not the only powerful JS library.

Comment: @gahooa: the gzipped version of a sub set of jQuery will be still smaller than the gzipped version of all jQuery.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio: this is true.  However, the transport time vs the latency of making the request will likely render this difference nearly insignificant, unless Sam has very special needs or very slow connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think of it from the opposite angle.  What you need is dead-code removal (i.e. remove things not used), not "include things that are used."

The only popular dead-code removal processor I know of is the Closure Compiler's **Advanced Mode**.  Beware I am **NOT** talking about *Simple Mode*, which only does minification and not dead-code removal nor any other optimizations.

jQuery, unfortunately, is not (yet) compatible with the Closure Compiler's Advanced Mode.

However, you can consider the Dojo Toolkit, which **is** compatible with Advanced Mode after certain modifications.  Read it [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t).

If you want to use a popular JavaScript library, but don't want to include everything, you can look into Dojo.

A Dojo application with only very light usage of the Core functions, after compiling with Advanced Mode, can be reduced to less than 40% of the size of a only-minified version (e.g. Closure Simple Mode).

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a tiny portion of jQuery on your site, chances are good you don't need jQuery. Have you considered a smaller library such as [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) or [head.js](http://headjs.com/)? Is there something particular about jQuery that you need that can't either be handwritten or found in a smaller library?

The minified version of jQuery is 82kb, and for speed's sake can be hosted on google's CDN. Check out the CDN Hosted jQuery section of this page: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: To Jordan's point, minified + gzipped, jQuery ends up being about 27kb (depending on the version). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. Except for css based selector which is [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) incorporated into jQuery. But I am sure you can write or find pure js library that has only the functionality you need and skip jQuery if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can have at jQuery in pieces: https://github.com/mythz/jquip

It is unofficial, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could feed jQuery plus all of your code through the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/); that would remove everything you weren't actually using.  I don't know how much smaller it would get, though; it might be all interdependent on the inside.

Comment: No.  The Closure Compiler in Simple Mode will not do dead-code removal.  Therefore it will not "remove everything you weren't actually using."  jQuery is not compatible with Advanced Mode which does dead-code removal.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, what breaks in "advanced" mode?

Comment: @Zack, a lot of things.  Too many to mention.  Advanced mode is *completely different* from Simple mode.  Best you should read up on it.  jQuery is *not* compatible with Advanced Mode of Closure -- so far, only Dojo can be used with Advanced mode.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm a compiler guy and I have read Closure's docs in detail, and for what you're saying to be true, either I don't actually understand what Advanced mode does, or there is some major gap in my understanding of Javascript-the-language (this possibility is much more likely).  I would really appreciate at least some pointers to discussion of the issues jquery has with advanced mode.

Comment: @Zack, well, among other things, Advanced mode requires that no property access be made via text strings or the [] operator -- these property names will not be renamed, so it breaks code because Closure renames everything else.  In other words, `foo["bar"]`, `var name="bar"; foo[name]`, and `foo.bar` refer to two different properties after compilation, one is `a.b` and the other `a.bar`.

Comment: @Zack, I have not read into jQuery sources too much.  However, as of the latest version, I believe the *official* line is that it is not 100% compatible -- which means that they have not rooted out all the ["bar"] or [name] property accesses yet.  However, I understand there is active interests (because jQuery's call-chaining mechanisms lend *very* readily to prototype virtualization).

Comment: @Zack, I don't doubt jQuery may be used successfully with Advanced mode after certain modifications (primarily to root out ["bar"]'s  and expand out mixin's etc.).  However, these modifications have not been made public.  Also, the large plugins library are not guaranteed to be written in a style that conforms to the compiler's very strict rules.  You only need *one* innocent statement for the whole app to crash.  Unfortunately this is primarily due to the flexibility and power of JavaScript that a compiler has to impose so much restrictions just to get to work...

Comment: @Zact, sorry to be rambling on...  :-)

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, that's very helpful.  I do almost all my coding in compiled languages so sometimes I forget the sorts of things you can do in a language like JS :)

Comment: @Zack, yes, the Closure Compiler is a really whacky thing. It is something that only Google, with its deep pockets and little bias against wierd ideas, would do -- and we are talking about like 10 years ago!